# How do I match input to contents in a file? I need a better explanation.

Tags: c++

My code below further explains. The user is asked if they have an account and if they do then the code is supposed to look into the file and match the user input with the content in the file. I've read that  is supposed to work with getline but I'm not understanding that part. I'm practically beginning C++ with a teacher that doesn't want to teach anything that isn't in the book.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string username[20];
  string password[8];
  string answer;
  string line;
  string fname, lname;

  ifstream ifile("Users.text");
  ifile.open("Users.txt");
  ofstream ofile("Users.txt");
  ofile.open("Users.txt");
  cout<<"Do you have an account with us?"<<endl;
  cin >> answer;
  if(answer == "yes" || answer == "Yes")
  {
    cout<<"Please enter your username."<<endl;
    cin>>username;

    cout<<"Please enter your password."<<endl;
    cin>>password;

    while(getline(ifile, line))
    {
      istringstream iss(line);
      if(getline(iss, username, ','))
      {
         //some magic is supposed to happen here. 
      }
    } 
  }else if(answer == "no" || answer == "No") {
    cout<<"Name: "; 
    cin>>fname>>lname;
  }



  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Concerning `std::getline`: Please, try google `C++ getline`. You will find plenty of links. [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) has the better reputation in this community but I consider [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) sometimes easier to understand.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking about. Do you need explanation of how `std::getline` work? If yes, then you should read references, do some examples which help you understand this function, otherwise please construct your question clearly.

Comment: @Scheff and Nort umm, getline retrieves the entire line, if I'm not mistaken, but getline is used to read a line in a file, right?  And when it's used for that I'm lost. And I was asking for more information on how to read information in a text file and match it to input from the user. Hope that clears some stuff up.

Comment: After call of `getline()` (and in case of success), pieces of the file contents should be stored in the resp. variables of type `std::string`. Next step could/should be to process that contents. You may compare the contents with something expected, split it into smaller pieces, or doing something completely different. (The answer makes a suggestion which seems to be proper for me.) Have a look into the doc. of [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to see which methods (i.e. member functions) are available.

Comment: To use `std::istringstream` for further processing of the `line` contents (read from file before), is one opportunity. (For me, this seems to be the more sophisticated way. The simpler whould've been to use character find and substring but that's a question of taste.) However, it means: Use the `line` as buffer which is read again (like a file) using the `std::istringstream`. Thereby, the 3rd (optional) parameter of `getline` comes into play which defines the _delimiter_ character. (Default is `'\n'`.) As the answer demonstrates, this way `getline()` can be used to split the line into pieces.

Answer (score 1):

These lines:

```
std::string username[20];
std::string password[8];
```

Are a big problem. They declare arrays of strings. Since you never use any element of such an array, just reading 1 username/password, it seems like someone did a bad translation of C code to C++¹. Just drop the array dimensions:

```
std::string username;
std::string password;
```

As for the "magic", follow the link from the comment. We can't help since we don't know what's in the file. **WAIT* We **do** know what's in the file, because

```
std::ofstream ofile("Users.txt");
ofile.open("Users.txt");
```

overwrites it. So the file is EMPTY. At least correct that.

#### More notes

```
        if (getline(iss, username, ',')) {
```

overwrites the username entered by the user... Maybe that *was* what the arrays were for? Anyhow, it doesn't look like you *need* to store the content of the file², so just use a separate variable:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9c93e3c45de2d3c)</kbd>**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string username;
    std::string password;
    std::string fname, lname;

    std::ifstream ifile("Users.txt");
    //std::ofstream ofile("Users.txt");
    //ofile.open("Users.txt");
    std::cout << "Do you have an account with us?" << std::endl;

    std::string answer;
    std::cin >> answer;

    if (answer == "yes" || answer == "Yes") {
        std::cout << "Please enter your username." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> username;

        std::cout << "Please enter your password." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> password;

        std::string line;
        bool verified = false;
        while (getline(ifile, line)) {
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            std::string u, pw;

            if (getline(iss, u, ',') && getline(iss, pw, '\n')) {
                if (u == username && pw == password) {
                    verified = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (verified) {
            std::cout << "Welcome back, " << username << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Username not valid or password incorrect\n";
        }
    } else if (answer == "no" || answer == "No") {
        std::cout << "Name: ";
        std::cin >> fname >> lname;
    }
}
```

---

¹ in C, a common pattern is to have `char[]` buffers to store raw string contents

² or you might need data structures that the book doesn't teach about ... :)

Comment: I'm a little bit puzzled about `getline(iss, pw, '\n')`. IMHO `getline(iss, pw)` should be sufficient as (a) `'\n'` is the default and (more important) (b) there shouldn't be any `\n` in the contents of `line` after `getline(ifile, line)`. Though, I wouldn't count this as critical as the input will stop at the string end as well. (I just checked doc. of [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to be sure...)

Comment: @Scheff It's not _forbidden_ to specify the arguments if they are default (in this case it clearly helps readability: it "reads the rest of the line")

Comment: I agree. Beside of this, there is still argument (b). Btw. I mentioned this as the questioner seems to struggle with these techniques in general...

Comment: Argument b is served by the same. If I hid the `'\n'` the reader might not _realize_ how the `std::getline` actually works. Now at least some people do :) There is **no other difference** leaving out `'\n'` other than reader awareness, and reader awareness is a GoodThing™ especially if the reader is struggling with these techniques.